# Postgresql dblink ERROR: function does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanted to call a function from another database using dblink

Created a connection

```
select dblink_connect('b_dblink','hostaddr=someHost dbname=paydb user=user password=pass');
```

After that I try to call a function located in another database

```
select * 
from dblink('b_dblink', 'select * from report_prov()') 
as t(id bigint, created_dt timestamp without time zone, amount numeric, status_id character varying, service_id integer, agent_id bigint, external_id character varying);
```

Then I get an ERROR

```
ERROR:  function report_prov() does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
CONTEXT:  Error occurred on dblink connection named "b_dblink": could not execute query.
SQL state: 42883
```

The function itself (select * from report_prov();), works well for me. But if I try to call it via dblink, I get an error

Comment: There is no reason for this not to work.  You are probably connecting to the wrong database or using the wrong schema or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing this:

```
select dblink_connect('b_dblink','hostaddr=someHost dbname=paydb user=user password=pass');
```

You should also create wrapper as mentioned below:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('dbname=postgres options=-csearch_path=');
 dblink_connect
----------------
 OK
(1 row)

SELECT dblink_connect('myconn', 'dbname=postgres options=-csearch_path=');
 dblink_connect
----------------
 OK
(1 row)

-- FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER functionality
-- Note: local connection must require password authentication for this to work properly
--       Otherwise, you will receive the following error from dblink_connect():
--       ERROR:  password is required
--       DETAIL:  Non-superuser cannot connect if the server does not request a password.
--       HINT:  Target server's authentication method must be changed.

CREATE SERVER fdtest FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER dblink_fdw OPTIONS (hostaddr '127.0.0.1', dbname 'contrib_regression');

CREATE USER regress_dblink_user WITH PASSWORD 'secret';
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR regress_dblink_user SERVER fdtest OPTIONS (user 'regress_dblink_user', password 'secret');
GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER fdtest TO regress_dblink_user;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE foo TO regress_dblink_user;

\set ORIGINAL_USER :USER
\c - regress_dblink_user
SELECT dblink_connect('myconn', 'fdtest');
 dblink_connect 
----------------
 OK
(1 row)

SELECT * FROM dblink('myconn', 'SELECT * FROM foo') AS t(a int, b text, c text[]);
 a  | b |       c       
----+---+---------------
  0 | a | {a0,b0,c0}
  1 | b | {a1,b1,c1}
  2 | c | {a2,b2,c2}
  3 | d | {a3,b3,c3}
  4 | e | {a4,b4,c4}
  5 | f | {a5,b5,c5}
  6 | g | {a6,b6,c6}
  7 | h | {a7,b7,c7}
  8 | i | {a8,b8,c8}
  9 | j | {a9,b9,c9}
 10 | k | {a10,b10,c10}
(11 rows)
```

reference for the above code is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/contrib-dblink-connect.html)

And as you trying to access the function from the other db, you need to give this function permission to the user as show below. assuming user name as **my_user**.

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_schema TO my_user;
```

The above command allows the execution of functions but not the access to tables. So, if my_user executes the function, it still produces an access error, if the function accesses tables etc. in my_schema. To avoid this, you may define your function as [security definer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createfunction.html):

```
ALTER FUNCTION my_schema.my_function(...) SECURITY DEFINER SET search_path = public;
```

Also an other way to give execute permission to specific users::

```
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION my_schema.my_function(...) FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION my_schema.my_function(...) TO my_user;
```